# How do you raise ValueError for input valuable in Python class?

Tags: python

I want to raise an Value Error for negative values of a and b. I have played around with this but it raises ValueError for different values and it does not seem to work properly.

```
class RightTriangle:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
            self.c = np.sqrt(a**2+b**2)

            if (self.a or self.b) < 0:
                raise ValueError("Negative")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Use the Pipe character '''|''' the do the "A or B" operation.

Comment: @MartialP While you're correct doing a bitwise OR before the inequality would fix this problem, I think it's worse for clarity and readability. I wouldn't use bitwise operations except where they're required, and this is definitely a case where they aren't.

Answer (score 2):

Fix:

```
if self.a < 0 or self.b < 0:
```

What you've got is evaluating `(self.a or self.b)` first. What this first part is doing is this:

```
if self.a: # anything but 0 is True
    return self.a
else:
    return self.b
```

So, you're probably going to get `self.a` most of the time, and then it's going to be compared in `< 0`.

Comment: No, you don't get a boolean here. Try `print(3 or 5)`.

Comment: @Matthias Thank you. Have my edits improved the correctness here?